# Is it possible to use a template for search spiders?

Tags: wordpress, web-crawlers, template, cloaking

Is it possible to use a special template for search engines and another template for visitors? on the WordPress platform.

Answer (score 1):

What you are describing is a technique called **Cloaking**, and it's frowned upon by most search engines. I wouldn't recommend you using it, as Google and other search engines may ban your site.

Search for this technique to learn more about it.

Comment: [Google's cloaking documentation](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/essentials/spam-policies#cloaking)